# sum function in camlx query - sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, caml

i have two list in sharepoint like:
LIST1:ID,Title,Visitor,Website
LIST2:ID,Title,MaxVisitor

i want to write this in camlex or caml query but i don't know how

```
select from sum(LIST1.Visitor)>List2.MaxVisitor groupby LIST1.Website
```

Comment: What do you mean with "sum(LIST1.Visitor)>List2.MaxVisitor"

Comment: yes Storm this is my point

Comment: Could you provide some sample data please for the two lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SPSiteDataQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for querying multiple list ,

Comment: what is this? I can't  understand